# How to get an output variable in matlab from handler callback

Tags: matlab

i have this handle callback in my matlab program:

```
% set the callback, pass pointCloud to the callback function
set(h, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', {@callbackClickA3DPoint, pointCloud});
```

in `callbackClickA3DPoint` function, I have a variable which I would like to get in the workspace of my main program.

```
function callbackClickA3DPoint(src, eventData, pointCloud)
selectedPoint = pointCloud(:, pointCloudIndex);
```

Currently, `callbackClickA3DPoint` does not return nothing and `selectedPoint` is the variable that I would like to get as an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this.

## Subfunction

One way would be to make `callbackClickA3DPoint` a subfunction of your main function and then any variable that exists in the parent function is able to be seen and modified by the callback.

```
function main()
    set(h, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', {@callbackClickA3DPoint, pointCloud});

    selectedPoint = [];

    function callbackClickA3DPoint(src, evnt, pointcloud)
        selectedPoint = pointCloud(:,pointCloudIndex);
    end
end
```

## `UserData`

Another option is to store the information in the `UserData` field of the figure. This would make it accessible to *any* function wanting to know the value *and* you can put any arbitrary data in `UserData`.

```
function callbackClickA3DPoint(src, evnt, pointcloud)
    selectedPoint = pointCloud(:,pointCloudIndex);
    set(src, 'UserData', selectedPoint)
end

 % Then in another function
 selectedPoint = get(gcf, 'UserData');
```

## Application Data

You can also use [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html?refresh=true) and [`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html?refresh=true) similar to the `UserData` approach above.

```
function callbackClickA3DPoint(src, evnt, pointcloud)
    selectedPoint = pointCloud(:,pointCloudIndex);
    setappdata(src, 'SelectedPoint', selectedPoint)
end

% Then in another function
point = getappdata(gcf, 'SelectedPoint');
```

Comment: Hi Suever! first of all thanks for answer my question.  I have been tasted all your suggestions but I still have some problems with my program. Now I'm using the UserData option; my problem is that I can´t receive nothing on my        selectedPoint = get(gcf, 'UserData'); because the handle never ends and that sentence is never executed. Do you know how can I solve my problem?  Thank you for everything.

Comment: @CarolinaSchoch Can you post your entire code on pastebin.com or something so I can see what you're talking about?

Comment: This is the first time I use pastebin.com so I hope do it well.

Comment: @CarolinaSchoch You need to post a link here so I can see it.

Comment: Esta es la primera vez que utilizo pastebin.com así que espero hacerlo bien. The first link is my function clickA3DPoint (http://pastebin.com/hxR6YMCF). Here is where I call the handle function callbackClickA3DPoint (http://pastebin.com/zh35zZKs). Also I have another script (my main program) where I call my clickA3DPoint function like: p= clickA3DPoint(vertex).

Comment: I am trying to select from the 'vertex' cloud points on my main program, some points which are interesting to me, and I need their coordinates. This vertex variable it's a 3xN matrix where the columns correspond to the coordinates and the rows with the points and I only want some of this rows. Thanks for everything :)

Comment: @CarolinaSchoch The issue is that `selectedPoint = getappdata(gcf, 'UserData')` gets executed before you click anything. You would need to either place a `uiwait` call before that line (to wait for the figure to be closed) or fetch that data from within another function which wants to use it.